# Page title not set in Google Analytics with Next.js

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, next.js

I have configured my Google Analytics in Next.js but I am having this weird problem that analytics is unable to detect my webpages, instead it shows `(not set)`. It seems that everything else is working alright.

I have added the script inside the `<Head>` tag of `_document.js` and checked many times that there wasn't any error in spelling.

Does anybody have an idea of what can be happening?

[image]

Comment: is there a title for your pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your pages do not have a [document title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title) set. Setting the document title in Next.js can be achieved using [`next/head`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head) directly on each page.

```
// `/pages/index.js`
import Head from 'next/head'

export default function IndexPage() {
    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>Index page title</title>
            </Head>
            <div>
                <p>Index page content</p>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That will make it for sure

Answer (score 0):

**Version Nextjs 13.2 onwards**

Nextjs 13 has introduced Built-in SEO support with new Metadata API.
If your page title is static, define a const 'metadata' in your Page.tsx file.

```
export const metadata = {
  title: "Your Page Title",
};
```

Ref: https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13-2#built-in-seo-support-with-new-metadata-api